# How to arrange responsive but absolute positioning of dependant elements of the image?

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

)
Seems i want to invent a wheel, sorry if so.

I have an image of a device and want to make it animated(not the proper word probably).
I mean i want to make buttons clickable as a menu parts. Imagine its a remote for TV or vynil player (if to click play button vynil start spinning), but i can't draw it - only the hq photo - top view. Some of the elements will rotate and spin on mouseevents. Ok, sorry for a lot of extra info, but maybe i am totally wrong in efforts.

I attach [a basic fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51zcuLme/1).

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <img id="img1" src="https://i.ibb.co/FxF2Qhf/main.png" alt="main">
  <div id="wrapper2" class="wrapper2">
     <img id="img2" src="https://i.ibb.co/Hqbrv67/circle.png" alt="circle">
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper3" class="wrapper3">
     <img id="img3" src="https://i.ibb.co/0FJj7Ys/rect.png" alt="rect">
  </div>

</div>
```

In other words i want to cut elements in photoshop and then make a responsive "puzzle" in html. A circle and rect should scale with main backgraound and stay always at their native places and should be functional elements with clicking events, rotating, etc.

I suppose that widths and heights, positioning should be calculated via js? But circles...

Sorry again if it is too basic and simple.
Looking forward to pointing me the right way)

I tried canvas (low experience), map/areas don't suit cause of animations and transitions need

Answer (score 0):

You should set relative image size if you want them to scale proportionally with container. Set widths in relative percentage of parent container.

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: max-content;
}

#img1 {
  width: 100%;
}

#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 28%;
}

#img3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 32%;
}
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <img id="img1" src="https://i.ibb.co/FxF2Qhf/main.png" alt="main">
  <img id="img2" src="https://i.ibb.co/Hqbrv67/circle.png" alt="circle">
  <img id="img3" src="https://i.ibb.co/0FJj7Ys/rect.png" alt="rect">
</div>
```